# Computer Hard Reset Issue

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, power-supply, nvidia-graphics-card

Wanted to get some feedback and ideas on a issue I'm having.

Certain video games cause my computer to **hard power reset** (as in it powers off with no warning then turns back on). I've identified **Darksiders** and **Age of Wonders III**, but there could be more.

Little back story. I build my own computers and this one is mostly new from earlier this year. I originally had a **Radeon R9 270x** in it, but decided to upgrade to a **MSI GTX 970** about a month ago. I also replaced the RAM to get up to 16GB.

When I upgraded I kept the same monitors, case, keyboard, mouse, blu-ray and power supply.

**My specs are:**

- Intel Core i5 4670K - Currently stock
- Asus Z87-Pro
- 16GB Crucial Ballistix
- MSI GTX 970 Gaming 4G
- CORSAIR HX Series HX750 PSU (around 5ish years old)
- Samsung 840 Evo 512GB
- Hitachi 4TB 7200RPM
- 3x WD Green 1TB

At first I thought that maybe it was the **PSU** having too much power drawn (it is getting a wee bit old) so I ran a CPU burn in test to max the power. No crashes.

Then I ran **FurMark** to stress the GPU. No issues, so I ran FurMark and a burn test at the same time. Again no issues.

Thinking that maybe it is a directx issue I ran **unigine's valley** benchmark at max settings. Again no issue. I also did a **clean uninstall/reinstall** of the Nvidia drivers (used Guru3D DDU (driver uninstaller)).

At this point I was starting to wonder if it was just Darksiders (the first game I saw the issue with). So I play **Far Cry 3** for a while (2 hours) and never had a crash.

But then tonight I tried playing Age of Wonders III and less than 5 minutes after loading into my save game, off the computer goes.

So back to troubleshooting. I pull the "new" memory out and put my old stuff in. Still crashes. I also check the power connections and everything seems legit.

I still have my previous video card (glad I haven't sold it yet) so I uninstall the Nvidia drivers and put the **R9 270x** in. Install the drivers and off to test Age of Wonders III. No crashes happen.

So at this point I'm not positive where to go from. I could try a fresh install of windows. Maybe going from AMD to Nvidia caused some issues. Oh and side note, this may be coincidence, but all my issues started the same weeks as I ran the Samsung performance restoration tool (for fixing the 840 EVOs).

I'm thinking about trying a **different PSU**. But if the R9 270x works fine.... From my research the GTX 970 only used about 30w more under load. But maybe that is enough?

Any thoughts or suggestions? I will of course RMA the card if need be, but I'm not quite positive that it is the issue yet.

Comment: Does the OS know that something bad happened? You never really mentioned it. Perhaps you could "Disable automatic restart on system failure"... pretty sure 7 still has that option. If you are getting a BSOD it is most likely graphics driver related but that might help narrow down the cause just to be sure. [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) can be used to view BSOD dumps quickly.

Comment: Yeah no BSOD and I did try disabling the automatic restart and still don't get anymore more than a kernel failure. Which seems to indicate hardware of some sort methinks.

Comment: I suppose you dont have another pc for part testing at this time?

Comment: I ordered a PSU on a hunch and it did end up proving to be that. Very odd but it happens. Now I just have to decide if I want to bother RMAing it since I already bought a new one (5 year old vs 7 year warranty).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if anyone is interested. But I tried a new PSU and it seems to have fixed the issue. Really odd I think though because I put my old card in and it had no issues. Granted it uses slightly less power (30w) and has two 6 pins instead of a 8 pin and a 6 pin.

Hopefully this info is useful to anyone else with a similar problem.